# creating a method overload with filestream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an overload method that accepts a filestream as a parameter instead of a string and i wanted to make sure that i did it the right way specially that i am not very familiar with filestream.

original method:

```
public bool DownloadFile(string getFile, string downloadToPath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(downloadToPath))
                File.Delete(downloadToPath);

            //we are not downloading collections, so return false
            if (_resource.IsCollection(fileToRetrieve))
                return false;

            _resource.Download(getFile, downloadToPath);

            return File.Exists(downloadToPath);
        }
```

overload method:

```
public bool DownloadFile(string getFile, string downloadToPath)
    {
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(getFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string filePath = file.Name;
            string filePathName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            int numBytesToRead = (int)file.Length;
            int numBytesRead = 0;

            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                //If file exists, the read will return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead
                int fileBytes = file.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                //Break when the end of the file has been reached
                if (fileBytes == 0)
                    break;

                numBytesRead += fileBytes;
                numBytesToRead -= fileBytes;
            }
            numBytesToRead = bytes.Length;

            //Write the byte array to the new file stream
            using (FileStream localPathStream = new FileStream(downloadToPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                localPathStream.Write(bytes, 0, numBytesToRead);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think this is the wrong way? Is this a question about FileStream or overloading?

Comment: This is a good candidate for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If the caller is passing in a `FileStream` then I would assume they would want you to output the data to the `FileStream`. Not to mention the `FileStream` already has a handle on the resource.

Comment: @tnw About the FileStream

Comment: Seems strange to take a FileStream then not to use any of its inherited Stream members.

Comment: @Romoku could you elaborate more about writing output data to FileStream

Comment: There is no need to check if the file exists before calling `File.Delete`. `File.Delete` will fail *silently* (i.e. will not throw an exception) if the file doesn't exist. And even if the file did exist when you called `File.Exists`, that's no guarantee that it would still exist when your program tried to delete it. See [File.Exists is only a snapshot](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/06/27/file-exists-is-only-a-snapshot/)

Comment: @spender this is why i shared :) because i am not sure of the proper uses

Comment: Ideally your `_resource.Download` method would have an overload that uses a stream instead of a file path.

Comment: One of those functions doesn't make sense. Either getFile is the URL you want to download from, then the overload makes no sense. Or it's an actual file, then the first one doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @nvoigt will i am moving from using the first method into the second - eventually but i have both of them for testing purposes and references. I just want to find a proper example in which a `FileStream` is passed in as a parameter and being used.

Comment: @Romoku could you possibly point me to a similar example i could look over - related to what i am aiming for?

Comment: Without knowing the purpose of the code except take a look at the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) documentation. It includes a number of examples on using `FileStream`.

Comment: @Romoku i will go ahead and take a look at that. The purpose of the code is that i am downloading files from a specified folder/location. An intermediate location, example: user uploads files to site - site makes a copy and uploads it to a folder/location. If anything happens to the users upload and say it gets deleted then a fresh copy of the original is still possible to download

Comment: @Romoku i changed my method above can you look over it and share any feedback. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method can be simplified down using the [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx). Your method will first read all the bytes into memory which is undesirable for large files.

[`File.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) is analogous to [`FileMode.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) and [`FileAccess.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) flags.

[`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx) is analogous to [`FileMode.OpenOrCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) and [`FileAccess.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx).

```
public bool DownloadFile(string getFile, string downloadToPath)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getFile) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(downloadToPath)) return false;

    try
    {
        using(var readStream = File.OpenRead(getFile))
        using(var writeStream = File.OpenWrite(downloadToPath))
        {
            readStream.CopyTo(writeStream, 1024);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // log exception or rethrow
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work in your case, but invite your attention on fact that *by definnition* stream, so `FileStream` too, can be not a file on disk, but some stream data, or someinfinit stream of data (tweets for example...).

By leaving with `fileName` paameter, you manifest your expaction inside method to elaborate with file.

So I would suggest to not add overload like this.

Comment: I wanted to create a a DownloadFile method but with a `FileStream` Parameter instead of a string. Eventually i will be using the method with `FileStream` and not the one with string but i have them both now for testing

Comment: I changed my method above can you please look over it and share any input